# SQL Server how to write query to distribute works to employees

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have 2 tables. One table contains employee specialty and capacity information. The other table contains daily work amount for each specialty. How can I write query (or queries) to distribute work amount based on employees' capacity in each specialty, no matter if the work amount is more or less than the capacities? Work amount is fixed values, employees' capacity can be adjusted to match the work amount but should be adjusted according to the capacity ratio. My target result table shows this "adjustability".

Table 1: Employee_Capacity

```
Employee    Specialty   Daily_Capacity
---------------------------------------
Aron Baker  DB2         10
Aron Baker  Oracle       5
Aron Baker  SQL Server  10
Justin Ross DB2         20
Justin Ross SQL Server  30
Tom White   DB2          5
Tom White   Oracle      10
Tom White   SQL Server  10
```

Table 2: Daily_Work

```
Specialty   Daily_Total
------------------------
DB2             30
Oracle          10
SQL Server     100
```

I'm looking for a result data table where all specialty's total daily works are appropriately distributed to employees based on their daily capacity:

```
    Employee    Specialty   Daily_Work
    -------------------------------------
    Aron Baker  DB2          7
    Aron Baker  Oracle       3
    Aron Baker  SQL Server  20
    Justin Ross DB2         16
    Justin Ross SQL Server  60
    Tom White   DB2          7
    Tom White   Oracle       7
    Tom White   SQL Server  20
```

Comment: It is more towards an algorithmic question rather SQL question. What algorithmic formula you derived for getting Daily_work in the result set?

Comment: Explain who do you calculate your Daily_Work column in the result table

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks, Kannan Kandasamy and luisarcher. To answer Kannan's question, I myself "manually" use a ratio, or percentage, to calculate and get the result values in Daily_Work column. For example, for SQL Server, total work amount is 100, while employee capacity ratio is 10:30:10. Then my "manual" distribution is 20:60:20 (which happens to exactly match 20+60+20 = 100).

Comment: To answer luisarcher's question, if I understand correctly, the Daily_Work column is to be calculated for the employee in the Employee column, so that they have appropriate work loads. For example, because of his daily capacity, Aron Baker get 7 DB2 works, 3 Oracle works and 20 SQL Server works for today. Of course I "manually" achieve this distribution. I just wonder if there is a query or series of queries I can get this.

Comment: @Yugang was wondering, because what  did was a small proportion rule and I was not getting your values, so thats why I wondered what was your calculation.

Comment: Wow. thanks all for your answers, Dheeraj Sharma, Jan, and SqlZim!  They look all practical and working for me. Now I will try every one of them and see which would fit my case and I will come back and mark the best answer that fits most. Thank you all so much! I need to come here often to learn more tricks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using aggregate window functions with the [**`over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause to determine the ratio of capacity each employee has for each specialty relative to the rest of the employees, and multiplying that ratio by `Daily_Total` to determine `Daily_Work`:

Note: this may not always work out based on rounding depending on your actual data.

```
select 
    e.Employee, e.Specialty
  , Employee_Ratio = convert(decimal(9,4),(e.daily_capacity*1.0/sum(e.daily_capacity) over (partition by e.specialty)))
  , Daily_Work = convert(int,round(
      (e.daily_capacity*1.0/sum(e.daily_capacity) over (partition by e.specialty))
      *d.Daily_Total
    ,0))
from employee_capacity e
  inner join daily_work d 
    on e.specialty = d.specialty
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/BYQE17707

returns:

```
+-------------+------------+----------------+------------+
|  Employee   | Specialty  | Employee_Ratio | Daily_Work |
+-------------+------------+----------------+------------+
| Aron Baker  | DB2        | 0,2857         |          9 |
| Justin Ross | DB2        | 0,5714         |         17 |
| Tom White   | DB2        | 0,1429         |          4 |
| Tom White   | Oracle     | 0,6667         |          7 |
| Aron Baker  | Oracle     | 0,3333         |          3 |
| Aron Baker  | SQL Server | 0,2000         |         20 |
| Justin Ross | SQL Server | 0,6000         |         60 |
| Tom White   | SQL Server | 0,2000         |         20 |
+-------------+------------+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: I selected SqlZim's answer as the best answer because it works and it is also simple (as Jan's) and answered thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem corectly, this is a simplified anwser.
You aggregate the data in first table and then join it with itself to get the numbers for counting.

```
select *,
 e.Daily_Capacity/g.DailySum*d.Daily_Total  from Employee_Capacity e 
 join (select Speciality s, Sum(Daily_Capacity) as DailySum from Employee_Capacity
 group by Speciality) g on g.s = e.Speciality
 join Daily_Work d on d.Speciality = e.Speciality
```

You will have to deal with rounding numbers, and converting types from int to float to not lose the decimals.

Comment: Thanks Jan. This works fine for me! I selected SqlZim's answer as the best because that is more thorough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Employee_Capacity TABLE (Employee NVARCHAR(15), Specialty NVARCHAR(15), Daily_Capacity INT)
INSERT INTO @Employee_Capacity VALUES
('Aron Baker',  'DB2',         10),('Aron Baker',  'Oracle',       5),
('Aron Baker',  'SQL Server',  10),('Justin Ross', 'DB2',         20),
('Justin Ross', 'SQL Server',  30),('Tom White',  'DB2',          5),
('Tom White',   'Oracle',      10),('Tom White',   'SQL Server',  10)

DECLARE @Daily_Work TABLE (Specialty NVARCHAR(15), Daily_Total INT)
INSERT INTO @Daily_Work VALUES
('DB2',             30),('Oracle',          10),('SQL Server',     100)

;WITH SOME_TABLE AS ( 
SELECT EC.Employee,DW.*,Daily_Capacity, Daily_Capacity/Divider Divider  FROM @Daily_Work DW 
LEFT JOIN @Employee_Capacity EC 
ON DW.Specialty = EC.Specialty  
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT Specialty Specialty_Ref,MIN(Daily_Capacity) Divider  FROM @Employee_Capacity 
                                                                        GROUP BY Specialty ) B 
ON DW.Specialty = B.Specialty_Ref 
) 

SELECT Employee,ST1.Specialty, (Daily_Total/ST2.Divider)*ST1.Divider Daily_Work 
FROM SOME_TABLE ST1 LEFT JOIN  (SELECT Specialty,SUM(Divider) Divider FROM SOME_TABLE 
GROUP BY Specialty)ST2 ON ST1.Specialty = ST2.Specialty ORDER BY Employee,Specialty
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! Your approach works! I also had something like this but not worked out as yours does. But I selected SqlZim's answer as the best-fit because his is simpler and also very thoroughly answered.